# Flask-SQLAlchemy How to filter two different models based on one to many relationship?

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm so sorry, there are a lot of question about this issue, but I just can't do it. I've been trying for literally two days.

I have three models:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    ### other columns
    oylar = db.relationship('Vote',backref='post_oylar',lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete")

class Plan(db.Model):
    ### other columns
    oylar = db.relationship('Vote',backref='oylar',lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete")

class Vote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"))
    plani_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("plan.id"))
```

I need to query Plan and Post based on Vote user_id.

Let's say I have this A user with Id 1.
Basically, I want to see which Plan and Post this user voted for.

I've tried so many queries that I can't even think of which one I should write here. But in order to be more clear, let me show you what I mean with this example:

```
post = db.session.query(Post).join(Vote).filter(Vote.user_id == 1)
plan = db.session.query(Plan).join(Vote).filter(Vote.user_id == 1)
final_query = #there should be something to merge these two queries.
```

It's been a nightmare for me. I don't know SQL syntax and I started learning with SQL-Alchemy, so please don't shoot.

Thanks for your time in advance.

**Update**: Solution that fits me best is using single-table inheritance. It has made my life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a many-to-many relationship with an [association object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object).
I think the models are okay, but I've restructured them a bit.

```
class Vote(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'votes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Foreign Keys
    plan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plans.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    # Relationships
    # If a user, post or plan is deleted, referencing votes are also removed.
    # The associated plans and posts are loaded with the vote using a JOIN statement.
    plan = db.relationship('Plan',
        backref=db.backref('votes', cascade='all, delete-orphan'),
        lazy='joined')
    post = db.relationship('Post',
        backref=db.backref('votes', cascade='all, delete-orphan'),
        lazy='joined')
    user = db.relationship('User',
        backref=db.backref('votes', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Vote(plan_id={self.plan_id}, post_id={self.post_id}, user_id={self.user_id})'

class Plan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'plans'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Plan(name={self.name})'

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Post(title={self.title})'

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)

    # All plans and posts that have been voted for can be reached via jointable.
    # CAUTION, objects can be added to the lists, but because of the viewonly flag
    # they are not transferred to the database during a commit.
    # An inconsistent state is therefore possible.
    #
    # _voted_plans = db.relationship(
    #     'Plan',
    #     secondary='votes',
    #     backref=db.backref('users_voted', viewonly=True),
    #     viewonly=True
    # )
    #
    # _voted_posts = db.relationship(
    #     'Post',
    #     secondary='votes',
    #     backref=db.backref('users_voted', viewonly=True),
    #     viewonly=True
    # )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User(name={self.name})'
```

On the one hand, you can use the ORM method using the virtual relationships to
list all the associated models. In this case, your table votes acts as a jointable
and the associated objects of the classes Post and Plan can be queried directly
via the relationship.

```
plan_post_pairs = [(vote.plan, vote.post) for vote in Vote.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()]
```

As an alternative, you can also write your own request.
As an example I'll give you both a SQL SELECT statement and a JOIN statement.
I also ask for the identifier of the vote to list duplicate votes by a user on the same plan-post combinations.

```
# SELECT stmt
items = db.session.query(       # SELECT ... FROM ...
    Vote.id, Plan, Post
).filter(                       # WHERE ...
    Vote.plan_id == Plan.id,    # ... AND
    Vote.post_id == Post.id,    # ... AND
    Vote.user_id == user_id     # ...
).all()
```

```
# JOIN stmt
items = db.session.query(Vote.id, Plan, Post)\      # SELECT ...
    .select_from(Vote)\                             # FROM ...
    .outerjoin(Plan, Post)\                         # LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON ...
    .filter(Vote.user_id == user_id)\               # WHERE ...
    .all()
```

The following example is a little more advanced and may help you in the future. All plan-post combinations of a user are requested including the number of votes for the respective pair from this user.

```
subquery = db.session\
    .query(Vote.plan_id, Vote.post_id, db.func.count('*').label('count'))\
    .group_by(Vote.plan_id, Vote.post_id)\
    .filter(Vote.user_id == user_id)\
    .subquery()

items = db.session\
    .query(Plan, Post, subquery.c.count)\
    .select_from(subquery)\
    .outerjoin(Plan, subquery.c.plan_id == Plan.id)\
    .outerjoin(Post, subquery.c.post_id == Post.id)\
    .all()
```

Comment: comprehensive solution!

Comment: @Kerem Nayman  I think you should change your model vote to make your work easier. Remove the column id and make the foreign keys all primary keys as well. Now you can add an additional integer column as a counter for multiple votes by a user on the same plan-post combinations.

Comment: You mean like this? Then how would I query this model? https://i.ibb.co/s967th6/Ekran-Al-nt-s.jpg

Comment: Since you have a generated primary key consisting of three columns, there can only be one vote with a specific combination of plan, post and user. An additional column amount is required in order to vote on this combination multiple times.

Comment: The query basically remains the same. You will now no longer ask directly for the id of the vote, but filter for combinations of plan, post, user and use the relationships. You can then use the following request to inquire about all plans and posts that a user has voted for. ```db.session.query(Plan, Post, Vote.amount).select_from(Vote).outerjoin(Plan, Post).filter(Vote.user_id == user_id).all()``` It's just a suggestion, you can stay with your current structure.

Comment: @Kerem Nayman  My intention was to reduce the number of database entries by removing the duplicate entries. The definition of the primary keys leads to uniqueness, 
which you can also achieve via [unique contraints or unique indices](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html). In sqlalchemy these can also be defined via [table args](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html). I cannot go into all of that here.

Comment: Thank you I see what you mean. I tried to show this list to users but these are combinations. Also, it turns out that Flask-SQLAlchemy Pagination only uses BaseQuery object for pagination. So I had to turn my queries in my original question into a list and use something else to paginate. And with this model you suggested it works without a flaw. So I think I won't use these queries that give me combinations of Post and Plans.

Comment: But I thought of using SQLAlchemy inheritances for these two models: Post and Plan. Post has a few columns, but Plan has like 15 columns in it. I really don't know much about inheritances. If I did that, would this make my work easier or harder with time?

Comment: I think inheritance helps when you split a model into several subtypes. In the case of Post and Plan, it doesn't seem a good option to me. You may be able to create a clearer structure through mixins. For me this is currently impossible to overlook. As far as pagination is concerned, this can also be achieved using the offset and limit functions of the query. I can understand the preference for the flask-sqlalchemy implementation though.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped more than enough :)

Comment: @KeremNayman Sorry I've solved the pagination problem. Are you still interested? ```post_plan_amount = Vote.query.filter_by(user_id = user_id).join(Post, Plan).with_entities(Post, Plan, Vote.amount).paginate(page, per_page)```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sure I will use this solution somewhere but I've basically used single table inheritance for Post and Plan models and it has made my life way easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating relationships to your `Vote` model, I would suggest you also establish a relationship between `Vote` and `User`:

```py
# Modify your class to include the following line
class Vote(db.Model):
    ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user = db.Relationship("User", backref="vote") #  <--- This assumes you have a `User` model
    ...
```

Now that that relationship is established, I would access these child objects from the `user-vote` relationship:

```py
# 1. Get your user
my_user_id = 1
my_user = db.session.query(Post).get(my_user_id)

# Get the vote for this user --> this will return a list
# Note: there may be many votes, I'll use the first index as a demonstrative example.
my_votes = my_user.vote

# If there aren't any votes
if not my_votes:
    raise Exception(f'User id={my_user.id} has no votes')

# 2. Get the first vote 
my_vote = my_votes[0]

# 3. Get the children from that vote
# These are the keywords specified in the 'backref' parameter
my_post = my_vote.post_oylar
my_plan = my_vote.oylar

# Finally, print them
print('post:', my_post.__dict__)
print('plan:', my_plan.__dict__)
```

As a side note, I'd suggest you do some additional research on how to [best establish relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html) in your ORM models – it looks like that might be the source of confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and response. However, this is unfortunately not what I want. Right now I can access votes for Posts and Plans. What I want is; I want to see BOTH posts and plans that the user voted for, not the Vote object itself. Theoretically, it would be like this:

Query = Query for posts that user voted + Query for plans that user voted.

Right now I can achieve this with two different queries, I showed them in my original question. But I need to merge them somehow, this is the problem. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in my Models, I'm open to suggestions.